# Create sub-folders inside app Templates in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I've created a sub-folder name `Housekeeping` inside `Properties` in my templates folder as can be seen in the picture below. I've done it to better organize things.

[image: Project template folder]

**Problem**

The situation here is that my UpdateView looks for the template inside the app folder `Properties` and not inside `Housekeeping`. This ends up showing me this error:

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /properties/1/housekeeping/housekeeper/edit
>   properties/propertyhousekeeper_update_form.html

Which in fact makes sense.. If I move the file to inside the `properties` folder it works fine.

For reference:

```
#views.py
class HousekeeperUpdateView(UpdateView):
    # login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'properties/housekeeping/housekeeping.html'
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
    form_class = HousekeeperAddForm

    model = PropertyHousekeeper
```

Is there a way to do this? Or can it be done?

Comment: Have you tried `template_name_field`?

Comment: @NageshDhope I've used `template_name` and it's working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `template_name = 'properties/housekeeping/housekeeping.html'`. Also remove `redirect_field_name` and `template_name_suffix`.

Comment: I've done it like you said and it's working fine. I didn't know that I could use `template_name` in UpdateViews, I've read the docs and didn't find it. Thanks!!